# LaTeX nomenclature define on first use?

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature

How do I define nomenclature inside the document on first use? Or even define it on every use? I use the `nomencl` package to define all symbols, but it just puts them in one page at the beginning. I want something like a glossary where the full definition is given on first use. I know I can use glossary for nomenclatures too but can I do it using `nomencl`?

Comment: Do I understand it right, that you want to define a symbol at one place and then get this definition displayed completely in the text when you first use it?

Comment: Yes just like glossaries

Comment: Then why don't you use the glossaries package? It works pretty nice.

Comment: Unfortunately i used nomencl throughout my thesis which is a lot of work. If I don't have any other option I use glossaries. I thought it was Ok to use nomencl, but my supervisor want me to define symbols on first use too.

Comment: The question is quite old and i am not sure i completely understand it. Can you improve the question by giving a minimal working example? Or even provide a self answer ny now?